# Add name in pdf from text input inside pdf react js

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I have a pdf file url (which has a text input in it), which i need to show to user fill his name and submit. I am using **pdf-lib** to add text field in backend.
In frontend i am using  **pdf-lib** to show pdf file,
Query
I have a text field, which i filled with dummy value, one man punch, when in frontend i change the value and click submit, i am still getting the same value, it's not changing t0 the new value.

Code to load Pdf file from url

```
const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url, {
  // mode: 'no-cors'
}).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
setCurrentPdf(await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({ dataUri: true }))
```

Code to show pdf inside iframe

```
    <iframe ref={docRef} style={{width: '100%', height: '35rem'}} title="test-frame" src={currentPdf} type="application/pdf" />
<Button variant='contained' color="primary" onClick={submitClick}>
                Submit
              </Button>
```

Code to get File after user enter his name and click submit

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(docRef.current.src);
    // await pdfDoc.save();
    const form = pdfDoc.getForm()
    const fields = form.getFields()
    fields.forEach(field => {
      console.log('Signature Value => ',field.getText())
      const type = field.constructor.name
      const name = field.getName()
      // console.log(`${type}: ${name}`)
    })
```

Here is the picture of rendered pdf

[image]

Comment: what you have tried ? share it

Comment: see this value signed, i added "fasdf asdf", but it is still showign one punch man, when i get this pfd from html

Comment: It seems, it's not updating the doc, as when i am downloading it asks for download with changes or download without changes.